# ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 201

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, oracle-11g

```
SQL>  select FILE_NAME,TABLESPACE_NAME from dba_temp_files;
                                   *
```

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 201 - see
>   DBWR trace file ORA-01110: data file 201: '`/oradata_nocg/temp01.dbf`'

In the database I don't have '`/oradata_nocg/temp01.dbf`', I am not doing any operation related temp tablespace  Why it is not allowing run above select query. ?

Comment: First you check your temp file is exist on specific location or not. from this query SQL>select file#,status,name from v$tempfile;  and SQL> select * from v$tempfile;

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is in a database that was cloned from an other database and the tempfiles are not added. Oracle needs a functional temporary tablespace to be able to process joins and sorts. dba_temp_files is a view that does this.

Solution is to simply add a few tempfiles to the temporary tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that oinstall has access to the directory to the file. You can do this using the following steps:
01 #chown -R oracle:oinstall {directory path here}
02 #chmod -R 775 {directory path here}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have similar case My database is up and running and yet gitting this error

- I removed older directories that has no files under it. With directories removed, the references of the non existing datafile is gone. It resolved the issue.